# Detecting which view has been pressed inside list item onClick

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to create an item in a `ListView` that has multiple options; **view** and **edit**. I would like to create it in exactly the same way as android's contact system - see below:

[image: Similar functionality in android contacts app]

I have added the red boxes to illustrate the behaviour I want. If you press within the left red-box, you call the contact. If you press within the right red-box, you send a text message to the contact. I have already created a similar layout in XML, but I am having trouble implementing this functionality in code.

I have tried to create custom `android:onClick` function calls for the separate layouts within the item, but calling an `onClick` method only allows you to pass in the `View` as a parameter, but not the position. Needing the position to use `listview.getItemAtPosition` function, I tried to use `listview.getPositionForView` to return the position but found this was **extremely** unstable and was very easy to return incorrect positioning due to recycling of views.

What is the best way of implementing a list populated by items with multiple buttons/layouts on each item?

Comment: Within your `Adapter`'s `getView()` method you get the position. Also in there, you can set the `onClick()` for the different `Views`.

Comment: Did you find the solution?? I've been wondering the same thing since i started to develop in android i havent came with an answer :/

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this while still using a single `android:onClick` function would be to utilize the `setTag()` method for each of the clickable views to store an Integer that is the position for the item. For example in your adapter's `getView()`:

```java
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    ...
    ImageView textMessageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.whatever);
    textMessageView.setTag(new Integer(position));
    ...
}
```

Then in your `onClick()` method you could do something like the following:

```java
@Override
public void onClick(View clickedView) {
    int position = clickedView.getTag() instanceof Integer ? ((Integer)clickedView.getTag()).intValue() : -1;
    ...
}
```

Don't know that it's ideal, but it allows you to use the XML `android:onClick` facility and doesn't involve creating separate `onClick` listeners for each list view item.

Comment: I've been desperately trying to get this to work. I have been using `view.getTag()` inside of the `onClick` function but it **always** returns null, even though I am positive it is being set in the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I also worked on a similar kind of project.
For doing it, i created my own layout having two linear layouts as **linearLayoutLeft** and **linearLayoutRight**.

I then added this layout to a listView.

And then i mentioned the **onClickListener** of the Listview, i used to getThe view being clicked at the position in the listView.
So for each row in listView, i had two linearLayouts and they have their own onClickListeners.

Comment: How do you add multiple onClickListeners?